# SELECT @local_variable=values from table where values can have multiple values

Tags: sql

I am using below query
`SELECT @local_variable=Adtid  from table where Adtid` can have multiple values stored into it. As I don't know what to use instead of '=' in @local_variable=Adtid. Can anyone suggest please what I should use instead of '=' so that my local varaible can have all values of Adtid

Comment: `@local_variable IN ('a', 'b', 'c')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable can't actually hold multiple values. You can declare a table variable instead, where you can then do something like

```
declare @tableVariable table
(
  Adtid int
);

insert into @tableVariable
select Adtid from table where Adtid ...
```

This puts the relevant rows inside your table variable. Now you can use the table variable to eg. create a cursor (to go row by row in the data - you can also do that on the original select if you only need to go through once) or use it in a `join` clause.

Comment: @user3265286 That's good to hear :) Please, don't forget to mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below syntax for get the Adtid as comma separator in result

```
DECLARE @local_variable VARCHAR(100) =''
SELECT  @local_variable +=  CAST(Adtid AS VARCHAR) + ',' FROM TABLE
PRINT  @local_variable
```

and another way as per below answer.

Comment: It's unfortunate that it's listed in the documentation for [`SET @local_variable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189484.aspx) rather than [`SELECT @local_variable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx), but "Do not use a variable in a SELECT statement to concatenate values (that is, to compute aggregate values). Unexpected query results may occur. This is because all expressions in the SELECT list (including assignments) are not guaranteed to be executed exactly once for each output row"